# Change line spacing for footnote text only

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, line-spacing, setspace

I have to format a document to this finicky standard: "The entire document cannot exceed 25 double-spaced pages, including all supplementary material, and must be in Times New Roman, 11 point, font. Endnotes or footnotes are not required for the writing sample, however, if included they should be in 10 point font and single-spaced, with double-spacing between entries."

Some investigation reveals that with an 11pt `article` document class, the "small" text size is about 10 points. Ok. So I did: `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}`. I'm also using `setspace` for doublespacing, so I thought I could wrap all the footnotes in a `singlespace` environment (or begin them with `\singlespacing` or something like that. That does cause the footnotes to be single-spaced, but it also causes (a) the footnote *text* to begin on a separate line from the footnote *number*, and (b) large spaces between footnotes, which is both aesthetically and practically undesirable (gotta keep the page count down, y'know).

How can I get the footnote style right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `setspace` package's `\doublespacing` command and the package option of the same name should *not* affect footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[1]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well I'll be. I wonder why I didn't notice that...

Answer (score 9):

I would use the `\footnotelayout` command from the `footmisc` package to select `10pt` as the font size for the footnotes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One should note that the extra space after the first footnote is due to the implicit `\par` after `\lipsum[1]` and won't be there if `\lipsum*[1]` is used.

Answer (score 4):

Perfoming a global `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}` -- as you report doing in your document to get the footnotes set at 10pt rather than at 9pt -- can have bad side-effects: there may be many legitimate cases -- besides footnotes -- where "true" footnote size (9pt in the case of your document) is be required.

It is thus more prudent to keep the redefinition of `\footnotesize` 'local' to footnotes:

```
\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}%
   \origfootnote{#1}%
   \endgroup}
```

With this setup, `\footnotesize` is redefined only within footnotes.