# Single spaced footnotes with bigfoot?

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, setspace, bigfoot

Can I make footnotes single spaced with `bigfoot`?  According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32281/4357), `setspace` shouldn't affect footnotes -- which is true, as long as I don't use `bigfoot`.

**MNWE** (modified version of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62560/4357)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=.5\textwidth,
  paperheight=12\baselineskip,
  margin=5pt,
  bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}[2012/07/07] 
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{R}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{N}

\begin{document}
First sentence.\footnoteR{Here is the first footnote, which gives lots of details that you may or may not find interesting.}\footnoteR{Here is another footnote.}%
And another.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do a similar patch as `setspace` does to the `\@footnotetext` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=.5\textwidth,
  paperheight=14\baselineskip,
  margin=5pt,
  bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}[2012/07/07] 
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefnstartbox}
  {\reset@font}
  {\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}\reset@font}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{R}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{N}

\begin{document}

First sentence.\footnoteR{Here is the first footnote, which gives 
lots of details that you may or may not find interesting.}
And another,\footnoteN{Here is another footnote.} with some text 
to see if doublespacing is really in force.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it was something to do with patchcmd, but I was otherwise clueless.  Much appreciated!  cheers!

Answer (score 1):

With bigfoot 2.0 and the extended main text (and required additional page dimension) from the accepted answer but otherwise the document from the question, I get:

[image: this output.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this an answer or a follow-up-question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- It is an answer (though it'd be better if it contained an MWE).  `bigfoot` 2.0 was just released yesterday; it promises to contain many fixes to long-standing problems.  I assume this is one of them, although it is not immediately clear from the documentation.