# footnote line-spacing with bigfoot and memoir

Tags: footnotes, memoir, line-spacing, bigfoot

I'm using `memoir` class with `bigfoot` and would like the main text to be one-half spaced and footnotes to be single spaced. However, the `\OnehalfSpacing` command somehow affects both. Apparently, the `memoir` class emulates `setspace`, so [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115987/single-spaced-footnotes-with-bigfoot) doesn't work for me.

I'm using XeLaTeX (TeX Live 2022).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{layouts}

\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}

%%% Book Layout %%%
\setstocksize{5in}{5in}
\settrimmedsize{5in}{5in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{4in}{4in}{*}
\setulmargins{0.5in}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.5in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\OnehalfSpacing

%%% Document Proper %%%
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean faucibus mattis ex id viverra. Proin ac porta diam, posuere sagittis enim. Nunc vitae urna dolor. Duis sed lorem pulvinar, porttitor leo id, gravida metus. Suspendisse eleifend elementum sapien sit amet fermentum. Nam tempus nisl in molestie placerat. Praesent pulvinar justo in diam porta pharetra.\footnote{Duis nunc nisl, venenatis eget tincidunt a, volutpat in lorem. Etiam tempus, nisl vel lobortis varius, nisi erat eleifend dui, sed luctus nisl felis dictum nunc. Phasellus et odio sed velit pulvinar bibendum id ut mi. Proin quis lacinia tortor. Etiam leo dolor, consequat sit amet augue nec, imperdiet fringilla ex.\footnoteA{Duis non arcu vel neque porta laoreet vitae a urna. Pellentesque gravida egestas ligula, vitae bibendum dolor egestas vel. Nullam enim augue, rutrum vel mauris ac, tristique congue mi. Sed erat diam, tempor a libero ac, suscipit sollicitudin nibh. In quam ante, tristique eget felis facilisis, maximus pharetra est. Donec vitae tellus justo. Nam tortor eros, faucibus et augue ut, consectetur dignissim arcu.}} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just patch it manually, resetting the spacing with the usual macro from memoir:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@makefnstartbox}{\SingleSpacing*}{}{}
\makeatother
\OnehalfSpacing

\begin{document}
Here is some one-half spaced text, pleasing the heart of whomever it is who
designs these silly rules requiring typewriter spacing in the era of
typesetters.%
\footnote{Well, probably, I should think so.  I've not actually done any serious
research.   The only paper I did find used documents prepared quite poorly, thus
vitiating the question.  Does double spacing help?  who knows.}
Down with bureaucracy!  Desks have ruled for too long!%
\footnote{Since at least the early modern period.}
Up with chairs,%
\footnote{Especially swivel chairs.}
let them rule instead!%
\footnote{Ever measured a bridge with a chair?}

\end{document}
```

[image: double spaced paragraph]

[image: single spaced footnotes]

This is standard LaTeX, since that's what I'm using; I've not tested on XeLaTeX.