# Weird space in footnote when the main text and footnote have different spacing

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I type this footnote

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{doublespace}
Hi \footnote{\begin{singlespace}
Footnote content.
\end{singlespace}
}
\end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

Then I get that weird space when I convert this to pdf. This is probably because my main text is double-spaced and footnote is single-spaced. But I want to keep it that way. How can I remove that weird space in footnote?

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32281/134144 could be interesting.

Comment: As leandriis says: With `setspace` the footnotes are single-spaced anyway, so you don't need `\begin{singlespace}...\end{singlespace}`. Just try it. I usually find it easier to load `setspace` as `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` rather than wrapping everything in `\begin{doublespace}...\end{doublespace}`.

Comment: If you are interested why you get the undesirable output: It is caused by the fact that `\begin{singlespace}...\end{singlespace}` does some adjustments with `\baselineskip` spaces at `\begin{singlespace}`. That causes the unwanted space here.

Comment: @moewe  @leandriis Thank you. I think I am approaching a solution. But when does `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package setspace` happen?

Comment: In this example you can only get a `setspace`  option clash if you load `setspace` twice. In your real document there may be other packages or classes that load `setspace` for you. (Or you load it twice in your preamble.) Impossible to say without seeing the document that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly missing something here. To me getting rid of most of your spacing commands is key. If not, let me know in the comments:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Hi \footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote spacing]

Comment: Removing `\doublespacing` and loading `setspace` as `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` might be even nicer. (The effect is of course the same.)

Comment: @moewe, way nicer! So nice in fact, I'll shamelessly update my answer with your comment. There, I've said it. Thanks a bunch, moewe!