# Set different line-spacing between main text and footnote

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, line-spacing, parskip, footmisc

I want to set line spacing: 1.8 for the main text and 1.1 for the footnote. Package `parskip` seems a good choice with some effective options. However, I can not make the different setting (of line-spacing) for the footnote.

I have looked at solutions in [This solution:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371138/change-space-between-footnote-line-and-main-text) [change space between footnote line and main text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371138/change-space-between-footnote-line-and-main-text;)

or [Other solution:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557880/weird-space-in-footnote-when-the-main-text-and-footnote-have-different-spacing) [Weird space in footnote when the main text and footnote have different spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557880/weird-space-in-footnote-when-the-main-text-and-footnote-have-different-spacing)

Both suggest using `setspace` to set the single spacing to footnote while double-spacing or onehalf-spacing to the main text. That does not fully solve my issue.

Thus, it would be appreciated if anyone could give me a solution for my desire. Please find below my try.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}

\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1.1}}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\linespread{1.1}}

\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pt}   % vertical space between rule and main text
\setlength{\footnotesep}{12pt}     % vertical space between footnotes

\begin{document}
 
\blindtext\footnote{I want the line spacing to be 1.8 for the main text; 1.1 for the footnote. In my understanding, package \textbf{setspace} can not help since it does not have the option to select the specific line-spacing for the footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, then merely adding the `setspace` package to the include list and choosing the `\setstrech` choice for `\footnotelayout` fixes the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{parskip,setspace}
\setstretch{1.8}% REPLACES \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 3pt minus 3pt}

\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1.1}}
%INSTEAD OF \renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\linespread{1.1}}

\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pt}   % vertical space between rule and main text
\setlength{\footnotesep}{12pt}     % vertical space between footnotes

\begin{document}
 
\blindtext\footnote{I want the line spacing of the main text to be 1.8; of the footnote to be 1.1. Package \textbf{setspace} can not help since it does not have the option to select the line spacing 1.8 (not mentioning others)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (Sorry for not making the question clearer.) Your solution is exactly what I need. It turns out that using both `parskip` and `setspace` is the key for my desire. Many thanks.